# IntelliJ Multiline edit at end of each line?

Tags: intellij-idea, edit, multiline

In IntelliJ we can do multiline edit at the same position on each line with Alt + Shift + Insert.  Can we do multiline edit at the end of each line when the length of each line is different?  A usage scenario is for editing semicolon at the end of each line.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible now.  Do a multi-line edit starting an any arbitrary column as normal, then press the "END" key and the insertion points will move to the end of each line.  Also supported are the HOME, and CTRL + left or right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a Mac and stumbled on this 10 years later, select your lines and press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>