# Multiline editing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to enable multiline editing like in [Notepad++](https://youtu.be/2P4x53CUeiE?t=43) or [Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039968/4313030)?

In these software you can create multiple cursor carets by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and selecting multiple lines with the mouse or the cursor keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple places (sublime) in code in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945536/how-to-select-multiple-places-sublime-in-code-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally found it. It works the same as in IntelliJ (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633404/4313030) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945536) Stack Overflow questions). Either:

- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click every line you want to edit. You can't use the cursor keys or drag with the mouse.
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> or the middle button of the mouse and drag with the mouse (clicking or using the cursor keys does not work).
- Double tap and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the cursor keys (you have to press, release, press again and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and then while holding it use the cursor keys for this to work).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to select the beginning of the same word appearing in multiple places in the same file (some call this function "sublime selection").

If you wish to edit the end of multiple lines, place the cursor at any position of these lines using one of the methods above and then tap <kbd>End</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Alt + Shift and click multiple locations to for multiple cursor.