# multiline edit in android studio for mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

Is there any shortcut for multiediting for android studio in mac.
I have to click with mouse for each cursor I have to place

**Alt Button** not available in Mac devices Like below
[Multiline editing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114740/multiline-editing-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You can hold the `option` button and drag the cursor on the lines you want to change. Then start typing.

Tested with Android Studio Iguana.

Comment: I was searching something Cmd-Shift-L as in sublime. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> for Column Selection Mode after selection.